# After message.abandon() in azure service bus queue, does it apppended to the end of queue?

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

After abandon method called, how will be processing of that message? is it appended at the end of queue immediately after abandon?

Comment: Is there any way to append processed message at the end of queue?

Answer (score 0):

When a message is abandoned, it is not re-enqueued. The operation solely removes the lock to allow another competing consumer to handle it. If you need to re-enter the message, you will have to create a new message and complete the original message. To ensure it's executed or rolled-back atomically, you would need to use a [transactional scope and send-via](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions).

Comment: Is there any way to append processed message at the end of queue?

Comment: That's literally what I've written at the end of my answer  There's no "built-in" option. You will have to spawn off a new message.